# How to pass an array more than once so it's sorted using C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Any help would be appreciated. This is homework and I'm having trouble getting an array to pass through a second static void and return the elements sorted from a user input. Please see code below. I"m having trouble getting the inputs to pass through functions properly for either one of the function for PrintArray/SortArrayHighToLow. I either get some 0's before the first element of array that prints the user's input, or it  doesn't compile and print the sortedarrayhightolow. It says System.Int32[].

Please help.

Thanks.

```
namespace HighScoreTable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // TODO: Ask the user how many high scores they want.
            //       Then read in their input.
            //       Support error checking (input validation).
            //       The user should only be able to input a positive
            //       integer value.

            Console.WriteLine("Input count of total scores.");
            string size = Console.ReadLine();
            while (!int.TryParse(size, out int k))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid.");
                size = Console.ReadLine();
            }


            // TODO: Define an array of ints, which will hold the high scores.
            //       Make the array the exact size indicated by the user above.

            int i = Convert.ToInt32(size);
            int[] score = new int[i];



            // TODO: Ask the user for each high score, and read in their inputs.
            //       Make sure to read in as many high scores are in the array.
            //       If the high score array is size 5, then read in 5 inputs.
            //       You DO NOT NEED to support error checking for each score;
            //       assume each input will be an integer.

            Console.WriteLine("Please input test score from 0 to 100.");
            for (int j = 0;j <score.Length; j++)
            {
                score[j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }



            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("High Scores - Unsorted");


            // TODO: Call your PrintArray function passing the array of high scores.

            int[] userScores = new int[i];
            for (int d = 0; d < score.Length; d++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(score[d]);
            }


            // TODO: Call the SortArrayHighToLow procedure,
            //       passing the array of high scores, to sort them.

            int[] sortedScores = new int[];
            SortArrayHighToLow(sortedScores[]);
            foreach (int element in userScores)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sortedScores[0]);



            // TODO: Uncomment the following lines

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("High Scores - Sorted");

            // TODO: Call your PrintArray function passing the array of high scores.

            Console.WriteLine(sortedScores);

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.WindowHeight - 1);
            Console.Write("Press ENTER to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // TODO: Write a function called PrintArray that takes as input
        //       a single int array, and returns nothing.
        //       The function will loop through the array and print out
        //       each int on its own line.
        //       Don't forget the keyword static.
         public static void PrintArray(int[]numbers)
        {
            foreach(int x in numbers)
            {
                Console.Write(x);
            }
            numbers = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This procedure takes an array of ints and sorts them in place.
        /// After a call to this procedure the array of ints passed in will be
        /// sorted from highest to lowest.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="numbers">an array of ints to sort</param>
        static void SortArrayHighToLow(int[] numbers)
        {
            int tmp;
            for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i; j > 0 && numbers[j] > numbers[j-1]; j--)
                {
                    tmp = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = numbers[j - 1];
                    numbers[j - 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're passing in a new, empty array to the `SortArrayHighToLow` method instead of passing in the array you want to sort. And the line where you declare the array is not legal syntax since you aren't specifying the array size (`int[] sortedScores = new int[];`). Also, what it the point of declaring the `userScores` array if you never use it?

Comment: OK, I've tried inputting i, j, and d and it doesn't come out properly. Am I to change something to an int for it compile correctly? Such as userScores? I'm also supposed to pass the value of the user input into 2 different functions. Have I done that properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your soft function works fine, just a little error on add array data. I just fix your code here, see my fix from "// liao fix from here" to "// liao end here"
First you create "new int[]", error, should be "new int[i]" need correct number, then you need add your data to your array, your System.Int32 error show because it have null

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
     class Program
     {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        // TODO: Ask the user how many high scores they want.
        //       Then read in their input.
        //       Support error checking (input validation).
        //       The user should only be able to input a positive
        //       integer value.

        Console.WriteLine("Input count of total scores.");
        string size = Console.ReadLine();
        while (!int.TryParse(size, out int k))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid.");
            size = Console.ReadLine();
        }


        // TODO: Define an array of ints, which will hold the high scores.
        //       Make the array the exact size indicated by the user above.

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(size);
        int[] score = new int[i];



        // TODO: Ask the user for each high score, and read in their inputs.
        //       Make sure to read in as many high scores are in the array.
        //       If the high score array is size 5, then read in 5 inputs.
        //       You DO NOT NEED to support error checking for each score;
        //       assume each input will be an integer.

        Console.WriteLine("Please input test score from 0 to 100.");
        for (int j = 0; j < score.Length; j++)
        {
            score[j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }



        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("High Scores - Unsorted");


        // TODO: Call your PrintArray function passing the array of high scores.

        int[] userScores = new int[i];
        for (int d = 0; d < score.Length; d++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(score[d]);
        }


        // TODO: Call the SortArrayHighToLow procedure,
        //       passing the array of high scores, to sort them.
        // Liao fix from here
        int[] sortedScores = new int[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < score.Length; j++)
        {
            sortedScores[j] = score[j] ;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("break, show unsofted score on array softedscore");
        foreach (int element in sortedScores)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }
        SortArrayHighToLow(sortedScores);
        Console.WriteLine("break, show userscore");
        foreach (int element in userScores)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Highest Score");
        Console.WriteLine(sortedScores[0]);



        // TODO: Uncomment the following lines

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("High Scores - Sorted");

        // TODO: Call your PrintArray function passing the array of high scores.
        foreach (int element in sortedScores)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element);
        }
        // liao end here
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.WindowHeight - 1);
        Console.Write("Press ENTER to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // TODO: Write a function called PrintArray that takes as input
    //       a single int array, and returns nothing.
    //       The function will loop through the array and print out
    //       each int on its own line.
    //       Don't forget the keyword static.
    public static void PrintArray(int[] numbers)
    {
        foreach (int x in numbers)
        {
            Console.Write(x);
        }
        numbers = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This procedure takes an array of ints and sorts them in place.
    /// After a call to this procedure the array of ints passed in will be
    /// sorted from highest to lowest.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="numbers">an array of ints to sort</param>
    static void SortArrayHighToLow(int[] numbers)
    {
        int tmp;
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j > 0 && numbers[j] > numbers[j - 1]; j--)
            {
                tmp = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = numbers[j - 1];
                numbers[j - 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}